# Jonathan mistaken as Jonaton

Tags: pronunciation, names

My name - `Jonathan` - is fairly common in English. However, several times people have typed it incorrectly as `Jonaton`. This includes both people with whom I spoke and people with whom I only corresponded. What is the reason for it?

Probably-unrelated note: I'm actually Israeli, thus my actual Hebrew name is Yonatan (יונתן). However, I can't attribute the above to my pronunciation, since as I mention it happened with people who never heard me speak.

Comment: I've often seen people spelling the name Jonathon, and some people spell their own name that way. I've never seen or heard Jonaton without the 'th''.

Comment: I think this is unanswerable because you're asking us to get inside the minds of people we know nothing about. Who are these correspondents? Do they know you are Israeli? Are they knowledgeable in Biblical or Modern Hebrew? Are they transcribing the name you have given them, or are they referring to some document in which your name appears in Hebrew characters or as a transliteration with 'J'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name Jonaton is a Hebrew variant of the name Jonathan, so it's fairly common for people to confuse them.

http://www.quickbabynames.com/meaning-of-Jonaton.html